# JavaScript detect if user is offline

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working on a web application. I'm using Appcache.
So what I want to do is actually dead simple: If the user loads the page without an internet connection, he'll see a button with the text "offline", otherwise with the text "online".
My first approach was to use offline.js, but it wasn't correctly detecting when the user was on/offline.

So I've tried this code:

```
function serverReachable() {
    // IE vs. standard XHR creation
    var x = new (window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest)("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"),
        s;
    x.open(
        // requesting the headers is faster, and just enough
        "HEAD",
        // append a random string to the current hostname,
        // to make sure we're not hitting the cache
        "//" + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.random(),
        // make a synchronous request
        false
    );
    try {
        x.send();
        s = x.status;
        // Make sure the server is reachable
        return (s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304);
        // catch network & other problems
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it seems, that XHR-Requests will fail when the page is loaded via AppCache.
Using `navigator.onLine` is no option, because most of our users are using Chrome.

Is there a solution?
Thank you

Comment: offline.js should be fine. what problem did you run into with that exactly?

Comment: I used
`Offline.check()` and `Offline.state`, but whenever I was loading the website from Appcache `Offline.state` returned `down` - the same issue as my previous code.

Comment: That's weird, look at this, this may help you: https://www.gavick.com/blog/detect-offline-browser

Comment: @RaahimGhauri I didn't load the script in the head, but at the end of `body`. Maybe that was causing the issue, will try. Thank you!

Comment: @RaahimGhauri No, this doesn't make a difference. When I'm not loading the page from AppCache, everything is working fine, but when loading the page from Appcache the state is always down even though a network connection exists.

Comment: That's weird... I'll see what I can do, but won't promise much.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.onLine *does* work in Chrome though.

Comment: MDN about navigator.onLine:

In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet.